# Android ListView with groups of 2 where each row in the group is a different object

Tags: android, listview, grouping

I have List, List each displayed in their own Activity. Now I want to combine them to show in ListView or similar view such that objects in the two lists are displayed in alternate rows. row1 object1 from list1, row2 object1 from list2 and so on. I do not want to combine object1 and object2 into a single object and send it to CustomAdapter. I can send the objects to CustomAdapter via public method or through an interface but how would I then handle getcount() ?

Comment: What have you tried already?  What specifically didn't work?  Try posting some code that we can look at and any errors/results that are unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like bellow. Though it's not a final solution, I just give you a hint.

```
public int getCount(){
        return object1.length() + object2.length();
}

public Object getItem(int position){

    if(position % 2 == 0){
        return object1[position/2];
    } else {
        return object2[position/2];
    }
}
```